# Convert integer to Roman numeral string

Tags: beginner, php, converting, number-systems, roman-numerals

This is my 1st time developing PHP code and I am only 13 years old. I have experience in other programming languages like lua, python, and c++.

This is a simple Number to Roman Numeral code I made for my mom because she had a hard time making herself one. Below is my code. Don't mind the names of the variables.

```
<?php

    $NumberRomanNumeral = array(
        1 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "I",
            "NearestNum" => null
        ),
        5 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "V",
            "NearestNum" => 4
        ),
        10 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "X",
            "NearestNum" => 9
        ),
        50 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "L",
            "NearestNum" => 40
        ),
        100 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "C",
            "NearestNum" => 90
        ),
        500 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "D",
            "NearestNum" => 400
        ),
        1000 => array(
            "RomanNumeral" => "M",
            "NearestNum" => 900
        ),
    );
    
    function separateNumberIntoUnits($n) {
        $separated = str_split($n,1);
        for ($i = 0;$i <= count($separated)-1; $i++){
            $currentNum = $separated[$i];
            $length = count($separated) - $i;
            $separated[$i] = str_pad($currentNum, $length, "0");
        }
        return $separated;
    }   
    
    function getClosestNum($numToFind){
        //echo($numToFind);
        global $NumberRomanNumeral;
        $closestNum = null;
        $foundKey = null;
        $closestMag = null;
        $differenceArray = array();
        $numLeft = null;
        if ($numToFind == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        foreach($NumberRomanNumeral as $num => $data){
            array_push($differenceArray, $data["NearestNum"]);
        }
        foreach($NumberRomanNumeral as $num => $data){
            $currentIndex = array_search($num,array_keys($NumberRomanNumeral));
            $romanNumeral = $data["RomanNumeral"];
            $differenceToSum = $data["NearestNum"];
            $previousDifferenceToSum = null;

            if ($num != 1){
                $previousDifferenceToSum = $differenceArray[$currentIndex-1];
            }
            $mag = $num - $numToFind;
            if ($mag < 0){
                $mag *= -1;
            }
            if ($numToFind == $num){
                $closestNum = $num;
                $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
                break;
            }elseif($numToFind == $differenceToSum){
                $closestNum = $num;
                $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
                break;
            }
            if ($closestMag == null){
                $closestNum = $num;
                $closestMag = $mag;
                $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
            } else {
                if ($mag < $closestMag && $mag > $previousDifferenceToSum) {
                    $closestNum = $num;
                    $closestMag = $mag;
                    $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
                }
            }
        }
        $numLeft = $numToFind - $closestNum;
        if ($numLeft < 0){
            $numLeft *= -1;
        }
        return array($closestNum, $foundKey, $numLeft);
    }
    
    function num2RomanNumeral($num, &$string){
        if ($num != null || $num != 0){
            $numArray = separateNumberIntoUnits($num);
            foreach($numArray as $splitNum){
                $data = getClosestNum($splitNum);
                if ($data != null){
                    $closestNumber = $data[0];  
                    $foundRomanNumeral = $data[1];
                    $numLeft = $data[2];
                    if ($splitNum > $closestNumber){
                        $string = $string.$foundRomanNumeral;
                        if ($numLeft > 0){
                            num2RomanNumeral($numLeft, $string);
                        }
                    }elseif($splitNum < $closestNumber){
                        if ($numLeft > 0){
                            num2RomanNumeral($numLeft, $string);
                        }
                        $string = $string.$foundRomanNumeral;
                    }else{
                        if ($numLeft > 0){
                            num2RomanNumeral($numLeft, $string);
                        }
                        $string = $string.$foundRomanNumeral;
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    $romanNumeralText = "";

    num2RomanNumeral(4212, $romanNumeralText);

    echo $romanNumeralText;

?>
```

I would appreciate if you give some tips and some things that would make the code better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a beginner it seems fine. There are some improvements that can be made. The points below are analysis of the given code.

Obviously there are examples of simpler implementations - e.g. see answers to [*Numbers to Roman Numbers with php* on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994941/1575353). While I wouldn't expect a beginner to write a succinct and optimized function  they are out there for the reader to compare.

## Avoid Global variables

The first thing I spot is this line near the beginning of `getClosestNum()`

> ```
> global $NumberRomanNumeral;
> ```

[Global variables have more negative aspects than positives](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/244085). Since that variable is never re-assigned it can be declared as a [constant](https://www.php.net/const) instead of a variable. Then there is no need to reference a global variable.

## Coding Style can be changed to be idiomatic

I would not expect a beginner to write code that always adheres to a standard coding style, but there are recommended styles that many PHP developers write code to be inline with. One popular style guide is [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). It has many conventions for readability and robust code. There are [54 errors and 1 warning](https://www.phptools.online/php-checker/result/78910947-c849-4c84-b2ca-c82765c56ab1) for the code above. Many of the errors concern spacing between operators, tokens, etc.

For example, instead of:

> ```
> }elseif($numToFind == $differenceToSum){
> ```

Idiomatic PHP code would be spaced like this:

```
} elseif ($numToFind == $differenceToSum) {
```

## Array syntax can be simplified

There isn't anything wrong with using `array()` but as of the time of writing, there is currently active support for [versions 8.0 and 8.1 of PHP](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), and since PHP 5.4 arrays can be declared with [short array syntax (PHP 5.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

So lines like:

> ```
> $differenceArray = array();
> ```

can be simplified like this:

```
$differenceArray = [];
```

## Variable gets overwritten

The seventh line of `getClosestNum()` is:

> ```
> $numLeft = null;
> ```

Then towards the end of the function, that same variable is assigned with the difference of two other variables.

> ```
> $numLeft = $numToFind - $closestNum;
> ```

This makes the first assignment (to `null`) superfluous. That line can be removed.

## Extra indentation level can be eliminated

Near the end of `getClosestNum()` are these blocks of code:

> ```
>     if ($closestMag == null) {
>         $closestNum = $num;
>         $closestMag = $mag;
>         $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
>     } else {
>         if ($mag < $closestMag && $mag > $previousDifferenceToSum) {
>             $closestNum = $num;
>             $closestMag = $mag;
>             $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
>         }
>     }
> ```

The second `if` (within the `else`) can be changed to an `elseif`:

```
    if ($closestMag == null) {
        $closestNum = $num;
        $closestMag = $mag;
        $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
    } elseif ($mag < $closestMag && $mag > $previousDifferenceToSum) {
        $closestNum = $num;
        $closestMag = $mag;
        $foundKey = $romanNumeral;
    }
```

This allows for one less indentation level for the lines within the `else` block.